# Solution for Multiplying a Constant times a Number with the same Numerator as the result

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have spent all day on this for a computer financial program I am building.I have the result of a number divided by the wrong number so want to divide it by a different number. Is there a calculation for how to calculate a constant to multiply by instead of multiplying by one denominator then dividing by the right one?

I have,

$(\frac{X}{Y}) * a = \frac{X}{Z}$ (how do I get a?)

example:
$(\frac{261}{26}) * a = \frac{261}{23}$

Clearly I can multiply and then divide by the different number

Comment: If I have understood the question correctly, $a=Y/Z$, which is basically what you have said in your last sentence.

Comment: Try $a=\frac{26}{23}$ for the last one.